# Como hace focus en vue sobre un boton

Tags: vue.js

Tengo un buscador que para desplegarlo solo tiene un evento sobre un icono de una lupa.
Al hacer click sobre la lupa se despliega una lista con búsqueda frecuente. Lo que quiero hacer es que al hacer click sobre el botón de cerrar esta lista, el `focus` se coloque sobre la lupa nuevamente.

Soy nueva con Vue y no sé si un método o en el `mounted` deba realizar el `focus`.

Comment: Agrega el código de lo que llevas hecho para poder ayudarte

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A tu boton debes agregarle el refs ([#REF](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#ref))

```
<v-btn ref="btnBuscar" @click.prevent="BuscarAlgo"><v-icon>mdi-search</v-icon></v-btn>
```

Luego en el evento de cierre de tu lista programas el focus al botón, por ejemplo:

```
this.$refs.btnBuscar.focus();
```